# No Module Named 'sklearn.decomposition.pca'

Tags: module, pip

I'll try the python code I found online. But I am encountering the error "No module named sklearn.decomposition.pca". I have imported the "sklearn" module but I am getting the same error. I imported it as "scikit-learn". I uninstalled and reinstalled it still didn't work. I tried all versions one by one. What is the problem, can you help?

Answer (score 1):

There is no module `sklearn.decomposition.pca`. There is a class [`sklearn.decomposition.PCA`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html).

Read more in the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#pca).